# How to generate 8 digit random number with UPPER case letter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help.I need to generate 8 digit upper case alpha numeric random number using Javascript.I did something but its its not generating like that.I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.getRandomNumber=function(){
  var rand = (Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
  return rand;
}
```

The above function is not returning like my requirement.Please help me.

Comment: What is not working? Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dw5p5sct/  What do you expect? Please make an example.

Comment: Does this suit your needs? `var rand = (Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '').toUpperCase().substring(0, 8);`

Comment: here i need first some upper case letter will generate with differnt date time and that up to lent 8.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke : yes,you were right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var randStr = "";
for(var letter=1;letter<=8;letter++) {
    randStr+= letter%2==0 ? String.fromCharCode(Math.random()*(91-65)+65) : Math.ceil(Math.random()*9);
}
alert(randStr.toUpperCase());
```

you could also use charCodes to generate alpha chars